# PySpark reading datetime as is

Tags: apache-spark, datetime, pyspark, timezone

I am using pyspark to load data by jdbc from mssql database. I have a problem with reading datetimes and treat fetched datetime as UTC without applying any timezone, becouse datetime is already in UTC.

Here on mssql i have a table

```
CREATE TABLE [config].[some_temp_table](
    [id] [int] NULL,
    [dt] [datetime] NULL
) 
-- select * from [config].[some_temp_table]
--id    dt
--1 2022-07-18 23:11:26.613
```

And I want to read it with pyspark by jdbc.
After reading it I have this in my DataFrame

```
df.>>> df.show(truncate=False)
+---+-----------------------+
|id |dt                     |
+---+-----------------------+
|1  |2022-07-18 21:11:26.613|
+---+-----------------------+
```

Timezone from server when spark runs:

```
# date +"%Z %z"
CEST +0200
```

So what I understand - spark is reading datetime and treating it as datetime with local timezone from server on which it runs. So it's getting '2022-07-18 23:11:26.613' and it thinks that it is datetime with +0200 timezone so it converts it to UTC like that: '2022-07-18 21:11:26.613'. Correct me if my thinking is wrong.

**What I want to do:**
Read datetime from mssql database by spark and save it into parquet without any conversion.
For example if spark reads datatime '2022-07-18 23:11:26.613' it should save same value into parquet, so after reading the parquet file I want to see value '2022-07-18 23:11:26.613'.
Is there any option to tell spark to treat datetime from jdbc connection as UTC already or not to do any conversion ?

**What I tried:**

- spark.conf.set("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "UTC") - just doing
  nothing
- serverTimezone=UTC - added to jdbc uri , did nothing also

**Note:**
I don't know if this is needed but timezone on mssql database is

```
--select current_timezone()
(UTC+01:00)
```

Comment: you could match the spark session's timezone with the server's timezone. see [this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-aux-conf-mgmt-set-timezone.html) for accepted types.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion, but how to set it from inside python ?

Comment: If possible, you could try using datetimeoffset instead of datetime to set UTC explicitly when creating the table.